# Not all code paths return value

Tags: c#

Here's my method:

```
public bool UserExistsActiveDir()
{
   try
   {
      const int ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 0x00000002;
      DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
      de.Path = "LDAP://domainname;
      DirectorySearcher objADSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(de);
      de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

      objADSearcher.SearchRoot = de;
      objADSearcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + txtUserName.Text + ")";
      SearchResult results = objADSearcher.FindOne();

      if (results.ToString() != "")
      {
         int flags = Convert.ToInt32(results.Properties["userAccountControl"][0].ToString());
         //results.Properties["userAccountControl"][0].ToString().Equals("514");
         if (Convert.ToBoolean(flags & ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE))
         {
            return false;
         }
         else
         {
            return true;
         }
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      lblError.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
      return false;
   }          
}
```

Where am I going wrong? It says missing return but as far I know, all my return statements are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no return in case

```
if (results.ToString() == "")
```

Answer (score 4):

You need an `else` to this `if` statement:

```
if (results.ToString() != "")
```

What happens if the string is not empty? You need to return a value for that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool UserExistsActiveDir()
    {
        try
        {
            const int ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 0x00000002;
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
            de.Path = "LDAP://domainname;
            DirectorySearcher objADSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(de);
            de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

            objADSearcher.SearchRoot = de;
            objADSearcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + txtUserName.Text + ")";
            SearchResult results = objADSearcher.FindOne();
            if (results.ToString() != "")
            {
                int flags = Convert.ToInt32(results.Properties["userAccountControl"][0].ToString());
                //results.Properties["userAccountControl"][0].ToString().Equals("514");
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(flags & ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
// <-here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
            return false;
        }          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no return value when `if (results.ToString() != "")` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

All of your returns are inside this if statement:

```
if (results.ToString() != "")
{
    int flags = 
        Convert.ToInt32(results.Properties["userAccountControl"][0].ToString());

    //results.Properties["userAccountControl"][0].ToString().Equals("514");
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(flags & ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But what heppens if `results.ToString()` is ""...there's no return value.

Answer (score 0):

There's no else for the `if (results.ToString() != "")` statement.

```
if (results.ToString() != "")
{
    ...
}
else
{
    return false; // or whatever fits in your logic
}
```

Or without nesting:

```
if (results.ToString() != "")
{
    ...
}
return false; // or whatever fits in your logic
```